# How can I get a type's precision?

Tags: c#, types, precision

Is there a way to get the maximum precision for a type or variable?

So that one does not have to use magic constants ... I assumed there would be something like `float.precision`, but I don't see it.

For float it would return 7, for double 15 etc.

Comment: not as far as I know, no

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Given the small number of types this would be applicable to, why don't you just hard-code it? (In one place, of course.)

Comment: Why don't you just add `precision()` as an extension method to `float`, `double`?

Comment: Thank you for quick responses. I don't have a free reign over the project and also wanted to make sure there's no standard built-in way first, before making any custom adjustments with on the level of extending base types, when I'm doing just a minor fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to discover this.  Core issue is that the CLI spec doesn't specify how a float or double is encoded.  It permits a CLR implementation to use a native floating point type that can have more precision than the predefined 'float32' and 'float64' types.

This is real enough, Intel/AMD processors in fact store floating point values with *more* precision.  Their internal format is 80 bits.  This design decision has been an unmitigated disaster, it causes calculation results to randomly change depending on whether the code runs in Release or Debug build, very small changes to code can cause drastically different results when the calculation loses a lot of significant digits.  The co-processor was redesigned a while ago to fix this problem but we're still stuck with the old problem in 32-bit code.  Microsoft cannot fix the x86 jitter, moving to the new co-processor design would break too many existing programs.

For all practical purposes, you can hard-code the precision to 7 and 15 digits.  Cast in stone by the IEEE-754 standard which dictates the encoding of single and double precision floating point values.  It is going to last for the next 50 years.  The non-practical ones are .NET Micro Framework apps that run on a processor without hardware support.

Do keep the *other* reason in mind why precision isn't exposed, it promises entirely too much.  When you calculate, say, 0.1234567f - 0.1234568f then you have only *one* significant digit left.  Producing a junk result in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for insightful answer!